# gglasso: predict type 'response'

Tags: r, probability, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

I am a little bit struggling to get the probabilities instead of the predicted classes using the gglasso (grouped LASSO) package in R.

The predict.gglasso only allows to specify type = 'class' or 'link'.

I have used the grouped lasso package to estimate a LASSO logistic regressio. lambda was found using cross-validation.

Is the correct approach to choose predict type = 'link' and then use the inverse logit link function on the output?

The gglasso predict function is shown below.

```
gglasso::predict.gglasso

function (object, newx, s = NULL, type = c("class", "link"), 
    ...) 
{
    type <- match.arg(type)
    loss <- class(object)[[2]]
    b0 <- t(as.matrix(object$b0))
    rownames(b0) <- "(Intercept)"
    nbeta <- rbind2(b0, object$beta)
    if (!is.null(s)) {
        vnames <- dimnames(nbeta)[[1]]
        dimnames(nbeta) <- list(NULL, NULL)
        lambda <- object$lambda
        lamlist <- lambda.interp(lambda, s)
        if (length(s) == 1) {
            nbeta = nbeta[, lamlist$left, drop = FALSE] * lamlist$frac + 
                nbeta[, lamlist$right, drop = FALSE] * (1 - lamlist$frac)
        }
        else {
            nbeta = nbeta[, lamlist$left, drop = FALSE] %*% diag(lamlist$frac) + 
                nbeta[, lamlist$right, drop = FALSE] %*% diag(1 - 
                  lamlist$frac)
        }
        dimnames(nbeta) <- list(vnames, paste(seq(along = s)))
    }
    if (is.null(dim(newx))) 
        newx = matrix(newx, nrow = 1)
    nfit <- as.matrix(as.matrix(cbind2(1, newx)) %*% nbeta)
    if (loss %in% c("logit", "sqsvm", "hsvm")) {
        switch(type, link = nfit, class = ifelse(nfit > 0, 1, 
            -1))
    }
    else {
        nfit
    }
}
```

So I have estimated a model and did this to get the probabilities (in-sample for now)

```
fit_model1 <- gglasso(x=x,y=y,group=groups_x,loss="logit", lambda = lmbda)

predict_insample <- fit_model1 %>% 
  predict(newx = x, type = 'link')

probabilities <- (exp(predict_insample)/(1+exp(predict_insample )))
```

Is this the correct approach to get the corresponding probabilities?

Comment: Looks like it, if you try the out of the box e.g. in `?gglasso`, the `data(colon)`. It looks reasonable e.g. if you do with that e.g. `fits.link <- predict(m2, s=0, newx=colon$x, type = 'link');
fits <- boot::inv.logit(fits.link);
plot(colon$y, fits)
`, s=0 is unpenalised I believe. Anyway, reasonable to assume it works

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help